# How to set page numbering from the third page in R markdown?

Tags: pdf, statistics, r-markdown, page-numbering

I'm trying to make a pdf report in R markdown and I need the numbering of pages to start from the third page. So it would be first and second page with no page number, the third page would be 1. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch off the page-numbering by adding `\pagenumbering{gobble}` in document preamble, then after two pages start the page-numbering using `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

```
---
title: "Page numbering from certain page"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
---

## Rmarkdown

\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\lipsum[1-5]
```

Comment: This worked and took seconds. Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver @shafee